# Why can't I find activity from app that is on device?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have the application that I want to open from another. It's an app I've developed before but android seems to be unable to find it:

```
   Intent   intent = new Intent("org.example.android.ExampleActivity");
   PackageManager packageManager =getActivity().getPackageManager();
   List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
   boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
```

`isIntentSafe` is always false and I've copied this code directly from android docs.

Comment: use ComponentName with both package name and activity name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
Intent   intent = new Intent("org.example.android.ExampleActivity");
PackageManager packageManager =getActivity().getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

You are asking the `PackageManager` to find an `Activity` that has an Intent filter that looks like this:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.example.android.ExampleActivity"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

This is probably not what you intended and is the reason that it returns an empty list.

When you create an `Intent` using the constructor that takes a single argument, that argument is interpreted as an ACTION, not a class name.

If you are looking for a specific Activity, you should use explicit Intent resolution like this:

```
Intent   intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName ("org.example.android", "org.example.android.ExampleActivity");
PackageManager packageManager =getActivity().getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

In this case, you create an empty `Intent` and then set the class name using an explicit package name and class name.